# Calling a JavaScript function from a Panotour Pro hotspot?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, jvm-hotspot, panoramas

I would like to call a javascript function from with a Panotour Pro virtual tour - from a hotspot, I cant find any examples of how to do so.

Ideally a lightbox / modal window of some type?

It says you can simple call a JS function from a hotpot using the UI without quotes as in
    helloWorld(this is a test);

and add this JS function to the same page as tour.
    function hellworld(s) {
         alert(s);
    }

Nothing happens, I have Googled this for hours, no luck, any help, appreciated..

I am happy to have a hack at xml main/tour files to get this working, just don't know here to start...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been playing with the JavaScript calls from PanoTour and it seems the tour must be uploaded to a web server before the javascript starts working as expected.

I added a couple of hotspots to a scene and added a JavaScript function call like this...
    LaunchColorBox(http://full-url-of-file.com/,title);

and then added a javascript function to page containing tour with same structure
    function LaunchColorbox(url, caption){
      $.colorbox({href:url, title:caption, width:"60%", height:"55%",opacity: 0.3, iframe:true});
    }

See following page source for further details of how I call/integration:
view-source:http://www.panoramus.co.uk/panos/arrowsmith/gallery/

Hope this helps, as not well documented.

Answer (score 1):

This may help, shows the basic format for calling JS from PTP.
http://www.autopano.net/wiki-en/action/view/Panotour_Pro_-_Hotspot_Properties_-_Link

**Java Script** 
Lets you call JavaScript functions from the tour. The function must be accessible in the HTML page containing the tour. Just write the call as if it was in a JavaScript code, but remove the quotes.

For example : “helloWorld(parameters*)”

You can use the following templates as parameters :
 %p : name of the current panorama
 %f : name of the XML file describing the current panorama
 %s : Fullscreen state when entering in the JS function

Comment: Yes I spotted that and of no use, as doesn't supply an example of it working seems strange as is a documented feature :)

Answer (score 1):

krapano uses  `js(helloWorld())` to call custom javascript functions

see: http://krpano.com/forum/wbb/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=998

Here are the relevant pieces of code.

first, the onstart item...

Source code 1

```
onstart="set(current_xml, marlin_creek.xml); js(show_name());

 ... this could be called from different areas...
```

The click me buttom references the same js function.